# define the panning of the slider when using ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I would like to change the panning of the slider appearance.
I have very long x-axis names therefore they are tilted by 90 degree similar to the example below.

```
data(gapminder, package = "gapminder")
gg <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, color = continent)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = pop, frame = year, ids = country)) +
  scale_x_log10() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
gg <- ggplotly(gg)
```

[image of the code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ4dV.png)

my problem is that the x-axis names and the x-axis title interfere with the plotly slider. Therefore I would like the appearance of the slider using something like:

```
gg <- gg %>% layout(title = "Basic Slider",
             sliders = list( 
               pad = list(l = 60, b=100))))
```

but I get the error message:

```
Error in p$x$layout$sliders[[vapply(p$x$layout$sliders, is_ani_slider,  : 
  attempt to select less than one element in integerOneIndex
```

Answer (score 4):

You can style the animation slider via the function `animation_slider` and the button via `animation_button`. Try this:

```
library(plotly)
data(gapminder, package = "gapminder")
gg <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, color = continent)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = pop, frame = year, ids = country)) +
  scale_x_log10() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
gg <- ggplotly(gg)
gg

gg %>% 
  layout(title = "Basic Slider") %>% 
  animation_slider(
    pad = list(l = 60, b = 100)
  ) %>% 
  animation_button(label = "Run")
```

[image]